# UK Careers site no different from international?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, localization

I've just noticed there is actually no difference on the Careers 2.0 "UK" site and the default site. I did a search for "PHP developer"  with no location entered and the results were exactly the same as searching on the default website(first 2 results were Germany and Canada) - You can actually just remove "uk/" form the URL and it makes no difference.

The location field for the UK site has a placeholder of "city, country or zip code" - the latter should be "Postcode", or even county.

Also, the geolocation is way off, it thinks I'm in Bath when I'm actually in Cambridge.

Answer (score 4):

This is intentional for now.  The main difference on the UK site is the ability for employers to pay us in GBP.  As for the content, we have a localization company that will be helping us go through the site to make the appropriate changes (like postcode) in the near term.  They're quite good and did the German translation work on the translated [/de](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/de) site.

Localized versions of Careers will look nearly identical to each other from the candidate's perspective (minus language in some cases).  We are adding in more geolocation features that will default the candidate view to more local jobs, but we're still working on this.

---

Update: We've completed the translation portion of the UK site.  Not much has changed, so definitely let us know if anything isn't, well, British enough.  We also had some hiccups with the geolocator, but that should be all set as well.